# Update weekly reminder Workflow when notification date is updated

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, sharepoint-designer-workflow, notifications, outgoing-email

0

I have strange requirements which are I think it is too complicated.

I need to send weekly basis reminders based on the Notification date column, I got already this solution figured out using Workflow 2013 thanks for that) and it keeps sending the reminder until the status column is equal to Completed.

Now the users sometimes revisit the item and change the Notification Date so the reminder is not getting updated and keeps stuck with the old date.

is there is a way to update reminder date every time user visit the item.

Comment: What version of sharepoint are you on?

Comment: it is SharePoint 2016 on-premises and I'm using workflow 2013 manager, I'm also using flag boolean variable with no luck.

Comment: In all honesty, I would probably tell you to look at SharePoint 365 and flow. SP 2016 on prem is going to be unsupported in 4 years so this development work would be defunct.

Comment: Yes I know about that:) but now I need to get this done otherwise my project will be unsupported. Also I tried doing that using power automate with no luck